# restriction on the size of excel file

Tags: r

I need to use R to open an excel file, which can have 1000~10000 rows and 5000~20000 columns. I would like to know is there any restriction on the size of this kind of excel file in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, your limitation in using R will be how well the data set fits in memory, rather than specific limits on the size or dimension of a data set. The closer you are to filling up your available RAM (including everything *else* you're doing on your computer) the more likely you are to run into problems.

But keep in mind that having enough RAM to simply *load* the data set into memory is often a very different thing that having enough RAM to *manipulate* the data set, which by the very nature of R will often involve a lot of copying of objects. And this in turn leads to a whole collection of specialized R packages that allow for the manipulation of data in R with minimal (or zero) copying...

The most I can say about your specific situation, given the very limited amount of information you've provided, is that it seems likely your data will not exceed your physical RAM constraints, but it will be large enough that you will need to take some care to write *smart* code, as many naive approaches may end up being quite slow.

Comment: Can you give some suggestions on what are those "smart" approaches? Any materials or link will also be very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I do not see any barrier to this on the R side. Looks like a fairly modestly sized dataset. It could possibly depend on "how" you do this, but you have not described any code, so that remains an unknown.

Comment: The approach I read csv file as testMatrix = read.csv("testMatrix.csv",sep=",") Will that make any differences on the size restriction? Thanks.

Comment: It shouldn't. Here's a small test of creating a 10,000 column data.frame: `ncol(read.csv(text=paste(1:10000, collapse=",") ) )` , notice: no error. And the overall size is as I said modest. I read dataframes that are 10 times that size. RAM does need to be adequate if you go higher than what you are at, but R is not the limiting factor.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers correctly discuss the memory issue. I have been recently importing some large excel files too. I highly recommend trying out the `XLConnect` package to read in (and write) files.

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx1024m") # Increase the available memory for JVM to 1GB or more.
                                       # This option should be always set before loading the XLConnect package.
library(XLConnect)

wb.read <- loadWorkbook("path.to.file")
data <- readWorksheet(wb.read, sheet = "sheet.name")
```